# iOS Webview loadRequest from string returns nil on ipad and ipad retina

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I've a menu on my app which loads local html file but it detects first if there is an updated file inside documents directory and if the file exists, the value of the html_path will load the updated file with its path on `docs.dir` of the app. This code works fine with iphone, and ipad retina 64 bit, but on ipad and ipad retina, the `html_path` variable returns nil.

```
NSString *html_path;

html_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                   pathForResource:@"somehtml" 
                   ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"];

local_request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:html_path]];

[_webView loadRequest:local_request];
```

Below is the error that I got:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, 

reason: `*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter`
```

I wonder the cause of this error, please help as I'm stuck with this error.

Comment: make sure that the 'www' directory is indeed a directory and not a group. If it's just a group you can use just pathForResource:ofType:

Comment: yes, it is a directory, i created that directory so that if i would have another local html file i'll just put it right there, as i have mentioned, the code works fine with iphone and ipad retina 64bit in the simulator, but just having the issue with ipad and ipad retina, can you help me over this one? i also forgot to mention, that the app is enabled as a universal app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue, it seems like

html_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                   pathForResource:@"somehtml" 
                   ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"];

that code above does not return the correct path, or the correct string path to be recognized by the NSURL fileURLWithPath.

the solution that i came up with was, i separated the bundle path and put that on the string

NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

then i use stringByAppendingPathComponent to concatenate the html file name

htmlFile = [bundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"www/somehtml.html"];

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this could be a problem with your resources not being included in the bundle for the application.

Select your target, go to "Build Phases" > "Copy Bundle Resources", press the "+" button and add your "somehtml.html" to the bundle.